# How to create slide animation in iOS objective c to slide a view over other like in amazon ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios-animations

I am trying to create create an animation to slide a view over other and if reaches certain point, it should invoke an action. Look at the screen shots from amazon.
[amazon pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anxbk.jpg)

[amazon pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAX3H.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement there are some ready to use control on github you have to more customize and achieve above requirement.

Please check below hand controls :

https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-do-slide-to-unlock.html

https://github.com/mattlawer/MBSliderView

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/slide-to-unlock

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIView's animation block...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

       //Do your stuff here...

    } completion:^(BOOL isFinished){

    }];
```